# This expression is not callable. Type 'NgForm' has no call signatures

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have created a basic signup from in angular and got this error

> src/app/developers/signup/signup.component.html:55:45 - error TS2349:
> This expression is not callable.   Type 'NgForm' has no call
> signatures.
>
> 55 <form #developersignup="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="developersignup()"   >
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> src/app/developers/signup/signup.component.ts:5:16
> 5   templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> Error occurs in the template of component SignupComponent.

ts file:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    
@Component({`enter code here`
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.css']
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {
    
  constructor() { }
    
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  developersignup()
  {}
}
```

html file:

```html
<form #developersignup="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="developersignup()"   >
  <table [cellPadding]="8">
    <tr>
      <td>Name :</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" ngModel name="fullname" placeholder="enter full name">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Email :</td>
      <td>
         <input type="email" ngModel name="emailaddress" placeholder="enter email address">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Password :</td>
       <td>
         <input type="password" ngModel name="password" placeholder="enter password">
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Confirm Password :</td>
      <td>
        <input type="password" ngModel name="confirmpassword" placeholder="enter confirm password">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="right">
         <button>Signup</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: You will probably face another problem when you solve this (or maybe you have already done that), but maybe you will need to import the FormsModule in your app.module.ts in order to work with forms.

Answer (score 4):

You used same name(i.e: developersignup) for ngSubmit method and reference Variable in your .html file. Below line for reference.

`<form #developersignup="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="developersignup()">`

Change name of anyone of them and you will not get that error.

For example `<form #signupForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="developersignup()">`

Comment: This looks like the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

Html:

```html
<form #developersignup="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(developersignup)">
    <!-- ... -->
</form>
```

ts:

```js
submit(data : NgForm) {
    console.log(data.value);
}
```